# Как сделать вывод даты Сегодня, вчера, и обычная дата в tableviewcell ?

Tags: ios, swift, дата

Помогите разобраться, как простым методом сделать чередование даты в TableviewCell. Например чтоб показывало, сегодня статья вышла показывало сегодня, вчера значит показывало вчера и потом просто шла обычная дата, ну а с форматом я уже разберусь длинный или короткий.Не могу понять как присвоить это.
вот мой код :

```
let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current

            let yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date)
            let today = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: date
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
            dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

            let yesterdayString = dateFormatter.string(from: yesterday!)
            let todayString = dateFormatter.string(from: today!)

            sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть простые методы. Для сегодня - `isDateInToday`, вчера - `isDateInYesterday`. Совместите их и получите резльтат:

```
var formattedDateString: String
if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(someDate) {
    formattedDateString = "Сегодня"
} else if Calendar.current.isDateInYesterday(someDate) {
    formattedDateString = "Вчера"
} else {
    // форматируете дату в yourFormattedDate
    formattedDateString = yourFormattedDate
}
// используете formattedDateString
```

Comment: а как мне это все указать в sportcell.dataSave.tex = " " ?

Answer (score 0):

> а как мне это все указать в sportcell.dataSave.tex = " " ?

Можно все это оберунуть в расширение. И у даты вызывать `yourDataVar.isTodayString()`